# Weird behaviour with UNICODE text on windows

Tags: visual-studio, winapi, unicode, wstring

I have some UNICODE text in my win32 code. 
I have declared it something like this..

```
std::wstring a = Träna; //swedish for practice
```

I copy that value into a variable using something like...

```
std::wstring b = a;
```

While debugging I don't see what im supposed to get in `b`.
I should be getting **`Träna`** in `b`, but what i get is **`TrÃ¤na`**
This is observed only on windows, the program works fine on OS X.

I'm sure its some rookie mistake, what am i missing here?

Comment: The program probably works fine on Windows too and your visualisation of the result is broken. (If you look at a white sheet through a red lens, it will look red. Does that mean the sheet is dirty?) You need to fiddle with your debugger settings or something. Looking at the bytes directly is the only way to be sure.

Comment: My guess is your source file should be saved with byte order marker ("UTF8 with BOM" encoding). Certain versions of MSVC have a bug where compiler can't detect source file encoding unless BOM is present and assumes that file uses whatever 8bit encoding is set on your system.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: No, he could also hit the bug I'm describing. Gcc and MSVC handle encoding in strings differently.

Comment: If you see “ä” as “Ã¤”, you are seeing a UTF-8 encoded character misinterpreted in windows-1251 (MS misnomer: “ANSI”) or some similar encoding. So this means that your debugger is using a wrong character encoding.

Comment: It would really help if you showed real code rather than fake code.

Comment: Two problems, starting with not using an L prefix for the string literal.  Further compounded by your text editor writing your source code encoded in utf-8 but probably without a BOM so the compiler doesn't know how to correctly read the file.  Text encoding just never stops hurting in C/C++.  You can't get a good answer without valid source code and mentioning the compiler version and/or IDE you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SigTerm and @jukka said above, the issue was with UTF-8 encoding.

After saving the cpp file in <**Unicode UTF-8 with signature**> the issue was solved.
The file was earlier saved in <**Unicode UTF-8 without signature**>.
It wasnt't the issue with prefixing L, i already have defined my variables like that.